# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Do you know what could be wrong here?

All variables are nvarchar.
The error occurs when @FunctionValue contains an INT in string format.

```
IF @TargetType = 'INT'
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQLSTR = 'UPDATE ' + @TargetTable + 
                        ' SET ' + @TargetColumn + ' = ' + COALESCE(CAST(@FunctionValue AS INT), CAST(@Value AS INT)) + 
                         ' '
END
```

Comment: You are trying to assign @SQLSTR varchar + an INT ...  COALESCE(CAST(@FunctionValue AS INT), CAST(@Value AS INT)) will be INT and can not directly concatenated with Varchar

Comment: @bummi what do I have to do then?

Comment: COALESCE(@FunctionValue,@Value) or at least Cast(COALESCE(CAST(@FunctionValue AS INT), CAST(@Value AS INT))  as Varchar(20))

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the ambiguity of the `+` operator.  When any argument is numeric, then it assumes you are doing numeric addition, rather than string concatenation.

If your original data is characters, then you can fix it by removing the cast entirely:

```
IF @TargetType = 'INT'
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQLSTR = 'UPDATE ' + @TargetTable + 
                        ' SET ' + @TargetColumn + ' = ' + COALESCE(@FunctionValue, @Value) + 
                         ' '
END;
```

If your original data is numeric, then you need to explicitly convert them to characters:

```
IF @TargetType = 'INT'
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQLSTR = 'UPDATE ' + @TargetTable + 
                        ' SET ' + @TargetColumn + ' = ' + cast(cast(COALESCE(@FunctionValue, @Value) as int) as varchar(255)) + 
                         ' '
END;
```

I also moved the "cast to int" outside the `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting a 'varchar' and an 'int' without explicitly converting the types. When this happens, the data-type with the highest precedence wins. In this case, Int has a higher precedence than a varchar, therefore the whole statement becomes an Int. And converting an int to a varchar inexplicitly is not allowed.

Try wrapping a 'CAST ... as VARCHAR' around your Int values:

```
CAST(COALESCE(CAST(@FunctionValue AS INT), CAST(@Value AS INT)) AS NVARCHAR(255))
```

For a list of data-type precedences, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309(v=sql.105).aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, however, although this makes sense, I still get the error.

Comment: Ah sorry I see you are using nvarchar and not varchar. You may need to cast as NVARCHAR(xxx) where xxx is the size of the data you need. Is it the same error that you get?